# Flutter: Best architecture for navigating between pages based off of a streamed database value

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

My app is built with a combination of Provider and Bloc patterns, but moving towards full BLoC. I'm looking for the best way to architect a solution, and basically just where to put this code and whats best practice.

I'm building a booking app, and my user has a field called `currentBookingId`. When this value is null, the user is left free to use the app completely. However, when the user makes a booking, I'm sending them to a `details` page.

Using Firebase and streams, where is the best place to listen for changes to this field, and to navigate to the appropriate page? They also need to go straight to this page when opening the app.

At the moment, It's just in my root `HomeScreen` widget which adds bloat and complexity. This is how I've made it:

```dart
    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();

      final database = Provider.of<DatabaseService>(context, listen: false);

      _userStream = database.userStream.listen((user) {
        final wasOnTrip = [some logic];
        final isOnTrip = [some other logic];

        setState(() => _user = user);

        if (!wasOnTrip && isOnTrip) {
          _navigateToCurrentTrip();
        } else if (wasOnTrip && !isOnTrip) {
          _navigateHome();
        }
      });
    }

  void _navigateToCurrentTrip() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(tripDetailsRoute,
      (route) => route.isCurrent && route.settings.name == tripDetailsRoute
          ? false : true);
  }

  void _navigateHome() {
    Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have dived into the docs a little deeper. Adding a Bloc Listener on both pages works perfectly and is simple to implement.
https://bloclibrary.dev/#/recipesflutternavigation?id=ui-layer-1